# How do I modify default android auto activity bar

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-auto

I am trying to figure out how can I modify the icons and interchange the order that appear in android auto navigation activity.

[image: Activity Image]

So far I have found this code needs to be modified directly in AOSP. The file that I think that is drawing this is [CarNavigationBarController.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/nougat-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/car/CarNavigationBarController.java)

I have not been able to figure out the resource that I need to modify the icons and their order.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Found the icon resources [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/nougat-mr1-release/car_product/overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/drawable/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
This bar is generated by Google's Android Auto application and it's **proprietary**.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Auto playback menu is standard, and the third party apps are not allowed to change the interface

You can only customize the color of the button, to distinguish your brand for some degree. Otherwise, the experience should be consistent and predictable to minimize the drivers distraction.